# Outer join not giving desired results

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sqlplus, outer-join

I have a couple of tables of which I am trying to join. Here are the two tables in question:

```
CREATE TABLE BRANCH(
BranchID        Int     NOT NULL,
Street          Char(50)    NOT NULL,
City            Char(30)    NOT NULL,
Postcode        Char(10)    NOT NULL,
TelephoneNumber     Int     NOT NULL,
ManagerName     VarChar(40) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT      BRANCH_PK   PRIMARY KEY(BranchID)
 ); 

CREATE TABLE STAFF(
StaffID         Int     NOT NULL,
BranchID        Int     NULL,
Name            VarChar(40) NOT NULL,
Street          Char(50)    NOT NULL,
City            Char(30)    NOT NULL,
Postcode        Char(10)    NOT NULL,
Position        Char(15)    NOT NULL,
Salary          Decimal(6,2)    NOT NULL,
StartingDate        Date        NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT      STAFF_PK    PRIMARY KEY(StaffID),
CONSTRAINT      STAFF_BRANCH_FK   FOREIGN KEY (BranchID)
                        REFERENCES BRANCH(BranchID)
);
```

I have written a join in the hope that it can join the two tables together using the BranchID rows shown below:

```
SELECT STAFF.Name
   ,STAFF.Position
   ,BRANCH.BranchID
FROM STAFF
FULL OUTER JOIN BRANCH
    ON STAFF.BranchID = BRANCH.BranchID
ORDER BY STAFF.Name;
```

The join doesn't work as I'd hope it would and displays the values in the following format:

```
NAME                                     POSITION          BRANCHID
---------------------------------------- --------------- ----------
Anna Jones                               Supervisor
Colin Stevens                            Assistant
Jack Butler                              Supervisor
John Walters                             Assistant
Mary Johnson                             Assistant
                                                               8000
                                                               6017
                                                               6016
                                                               6015
                                                               8001
```

The problem being that the branchID's do not get assigned to the relevant staff names. Is it possible to do this somehow? So that the branchID's appear in the same rows as the Staff name's and positions. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the `BranchID` null in the `STAFF` table?

Comment: It is hard to analyse the output without having an input data.

Comment: Oh sorry I can show what I put into each table if that helps? and yes it is null, is that the problem?

Comment: The `BranchID` is `NULL` in the `staff` table.  You have a foreign key constraint and the values don't match.  The only way that can happen is with `NULL` values.  You can see these if you include `STAFF.BranchId` in the `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FULL OUTER JOIN` would get you rows from both the tables regardless of whether the join condition is satisfied or not. You can use an `INNER JOIN` to get the information, as below:

```
SELECT STAFF.Name
   ,STAFF.Position
   ,BRANCH.BranchID
FROM STAFF
INNER JOIN BRANCH
    ON STAFF.BranchID = BRANCH.BranchID
ORDER BY STAFF.Name;
```

However, it also appears that your data is not correct. `STAFF.BranchID` appears to be `NULL`.

Comment: The problem was relating to the data, staff.branchID being null, have used the join as above now after changing the data with much better results. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `FULL OUTER JOIN` keyword returns all rows from the left table (`STAFF` in your case) and from the right table (`BRANCH` in your case).

Your actual result looks like there are no matching rows with your join over BranchID.

Why do you need `FULL OUTER JOIN` at all?

Try the following query instead to get only rows from both table which match over BranchID:

```
SELECT
    STAFF.Name
    ,STAFF.Position
    ,BRANCH.BranchID

FROM
    STAFF JOIN BRANCH ON STAFF.BranchID = BRANCH.BranchID

ORDER BY
    STAFF.Name
```